# How bash handle parsing errors?

Tags: bash, parsing, error-handling

For context, i'm trying to create an overly simplified version of bash, not like a bash full script interpreter, just a series of commands and operators `(|,||, &&, <, >, <<, >>,$, $?)` small interpreter, The mental model which i used in a nutshell is:

- Lexer + Expander: in the first stage i used a simple state machine to lex and store data (commands, arguments, redirection files etc.) and lex input into tokens, i expand env variables and i handle lexical errors too.(as simple as checking finite states of valid characters).
- Parser: in the second i stage i intend to create an AST out of the tokens + data, and handle parsing errors.
- Executor: Finally i'll execute the AST.

No i'm at the parser stage, and i'm trying to think about how might i handle parsing errors, now the thought i had is out of the possible range  of valid statements, it seems very difficult to check the validity of such an input cause the range is too big or at least that's what i think, and i'm sure there's some generalized solution for the problem, why i'm sure? because bash have done it.
For example this statement:

```
$ < $FILE || && > outfile
```

From the lexer point of view it's all bright and shiny, but it's surely not a valid input from the parser's perspective. Now one possible solution to this is to check whether there's a command token in the input if not then invalid. but what about this one:

```
$ || ls > $FILE && cat < $FILE
```

Again all valid lexeme, but unparsable statement, maybe that too could be checked against "if the line start with an OR or AND token error.".
Now the specific question is **how bash exactly parse these combination of commands and operators,** either there's some sort of more generalized solution or i'm left with an if&else error checking against inputs that i think is invalid. which honestly seems stupid and cumbersome.

Comment: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the complexity of shell parsing is in the tokenisation, although you certainly don't need to worry about all of the complications which have crept in over the years. The grammar itself is pretty simple; it's designed to be parsed by a parser generated with a tool like Bison (or some other yacc derivative), and that's precisely how Bash works.

The various syntactic rules recognised by Bash are scattered throughout the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), but the grammar is based on the standard shell grammar specified in the Posix standard, which is probably an easier starting point. In that document, the grammar is included as what is basically a Yacc input file (without any of the semantic actions necessary for an actual implementation); you can find it at the end of [section 2.10](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10). Make sure to read the initial part of that section, though, because it contains important information about how tokens are classified. Also, take note of [section 2.3, token recognition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03).

Between these two sections you'll find a precise description of shell quoting rules and the various expansions which are done prior to parsing (or, better said, intermingled with parsing because [command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) makes the whole process recursive.) You might not want to absorb all of that on a first reading, although it will also help you be more effective in your use of the shell.

Bash implements a lot more features, but probably most or all of them go beyond your needs.

Answer (score 1):

[@choroba has the right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72303115/how-bash-handle-parsing-errors#comment127735792_72303115) - to understand *exactly* how Bash parses scripts you need to look at the source of Bash. There are basically fractal rules of thumb for how Bash works in increasingly complex cases, and any description short enough to fit in a SO response is probably not detailed enough to give you the full picture.